# How can I write output from a GUI game created in JavaFX to another JavaFX scene to create a scoreboard?

Tags: java, javafx

I have been working on creating the Game of Pig, a dice game. I have quite a bit of code here and I am lost trying to solve one bug, and I am looking for suggestions or resources on how to populate my scoreboard within my GUI.

The bug I have: why is it when the ROLL AGAIN button that the p1TurnField and p2TurnField do not populate? They were working correctly yesterday, I added some more logic to my game and then all of the sudden they stopped populating, and I cannot figure out the error at all. Once the HOLD button is pressed, the score accumulated in the turn is added to the p1ScoreField and p2ScoreField appropriately, but the game should also tally the p1TurnField and p2TurnField on that player's turn.

I am not sure where to begin on populating the scoreboard, but I suspect I will need to brush up on streams and lambda expressions.

Also, I apologize, but I am not sure how to upload the resource files to this post, but 1.png through 6.png are pictures of each side of a die, and 0.png is a default picture for when the game starts/ends.

**EDIT: Bug fixed! I called the tallyPlayerScores() method on my rollAgain() method and that solved my bug!**

[Click here for a sample of my game's GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kxWa.png)

Main.java

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Die.java

```
package application;

public class Die {
    private int top;
    private int maxNumberOfSides;

    public Die() {
        top = 0;
        maxNumberOfSides = 6;
    }

    public int getTop() {
        return top;
    }

    public void rollDie() {
        top = (int)(Math.random() * maxNumberOfSides) + 1;
    }

}
```

Player.java

```
package application;

public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int scoreForCurrentTurn;
    private int runningTotal;
    
    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        scoreForCurrentTurn = 0;
        runningTotal = 0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getScoreForCurrentTurn() {
        return scoreForCurrentTurn;
    }

    public int getRunningTotal() {
        return runningTotal;
    }
    
    public void resetScoreForCurrentTurn() {
        scoreForCurrentTurn = 0;
    }
    
    public void addPoints(int roll) {
        scoreForCurrentTurn += roll;
    }
    
    public void addPointsRunningTotal() {
        runningTotal += scoreForCurrentTurn;
        resetScoreForCurrentTurn();
    }
    
    public void resetRunningTotal() {
        runningTotal = 0;
    }
    
}
```

GamePlay.java

```
package application;

public class GamePlay {
    private Die die;
    private Player p1;
    private Player p2;
    private Player currentPlayer;
    public static final int maxScore = 100;

    public GamePlay(String nameOfP1, String nameOfP2) {
        die = new Die();
        p1 = new Player(nameOfP1);
        p2 = new Player(nameOfP2); 
        currentPlayer = p1;
    }

    public Die getDie() {
        return die;
    }

    public Player getP1() {
        return p1;
    }

    public Player getP2() {
        return p2;
    }

    public Player getCurrentPlayer() {
        return currentPlayer;
    }

    public boolean gameHasBeenWon() {
        return currentPlayer.getRunningTotal() >= maxScore;
    }

    public boolean p1Turn() {
        return currentPlayer == p1;
    }

    public void switchTurns() {
        if(p1Turn()) {
            currentPlayer = p2;
        }
        else {
            currentPlayer = p1;
        }
    }

    public void roll() {
        die.rollDie();
        int top = die.getTop();
        currentPlayer.addPoints(top);
        if (top == 1) {
            currentPlayer.resetScoreForCurrentTurn();
            switchTurns();
        }
    }

    public void hold() {
        currentPlayer.addPointsRunningTotal();
        if(!gameHasBeenWon()) {
            switchTurns();
        }
    }

}
```

SampleController.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleController {
    GamePlay game;
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    
    @FXML
    Label p1Label;
    
    @FXML
    Label p2Label;
    
    @FXML
    Label gameTitle;
    
    @FXML
    ImageView dieImg;
    
    @FXML
    Button holdButton;
    
    @FXML
    Button rollButton;
    
    @FXML
    Button scoreButton;
    
    @FXML
    Button newGameButton;
    
    @FXML
    TextField p1ScoreField;
    
    @FXML
    TextField p2ScoreField;
    
    @FXML
    TextField p1TurnField;
    
    @FXML
    TextField p2TurnField;
    
    @FXML 
    public void initialize() {
        game = new GamePlay("P1", "P2");
        tallyPlayerScores();
    }
    
    public void setDieImg(int random) {
        dieImg.setImage(new Image("/" + random + ".png"));
    }
    
    public void rollAgain() {
        game.roll();
        setDieImg(game.getDie().getTop());
    }
    
    public void holdScore() {
        game.hold();
        tallyPlayerScores();
        dieImg.setImage(new Image("/0.png"));
    }
    
    public void checkTurn() {
        if(game.p1Turn()) {
            p1Label.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
            p2Label.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else {
            p2Label.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
            p1Label.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
        if(game.gameHasBeenWon()) {
            gameTitle.setText("Game Over!" + game.getCurrentPlayer().getName() + " won the game!");
        }

    }
    
    public void tallyPlayerScores() {
        setDieImg(game.getDie().getTop());
        p1TurnField.setText("" + game.getP1().getScoreForCurrentTurn());
        p1ScoreField.setText("" + game.getP1().getRunningTotal());
        p2TurnField.setText("" + game.getP2().getScoreForCurrentTurn());
        p2ScoreField.setText("" + game.getP2().getRunningTotal());
        checkTurn();
    }
    
    public void displayPastScores(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        Parent root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scores.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public void displayPigGame(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        Parent root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public void newGame() {
        game.getP1().resetRunningTotal();
        game.getP1().resetScoreForCurrentTurn();
        game.getP2().resetRunningTotal();
        game.getP2().resetScoreForCurrentTurn();
        tallyPlayerScores();
        dieImg.setImage(new Image("/0.png"));
    }
    
}
```

ScoresController.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScoresController {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    
    @FXML
    Button exitButton;
    
    public void displayPigGame(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        Parent root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public void quitProgram() {
        exitButton.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            Platform.exit();
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: good that you solved your problem yourself :) For the next question, please note that you should provide a [mcve] demonstrating just the problem (_not_ your complete code) - either strip the complete down to contain nothing but problem related or write code just for demonstration.

Comment: @kleopatra thank you for that info. I will remember for next time. I didn't want to provide too little code, so that is why I put the entirety of it on my post.

Comment: next time it will be :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).